# Should the Rayleigh scattering of blue light somehow 'paint' the Moon image in the sky slightly in blue?

Tags: visible-light, scattering, atmospheric-science, moon

Should the Rayleigh scattering of blue light somehow 'paint' the Moon image in the sky slightly in blue? Maybe the Moon light is too intense  during the day for that kind of effect to take place as facts show a predominantly white Moon image?

Comment: Just to check if I'm understanding -- are you asking whether some photons which are Rayleigh scattered in the Earth's atmosphere, are scattered in the direction of the moon, reflect off the moon, and return to Earth, which should add blue light to the color of the moon we observe? Or are you asking about a different mechanism?

Comment: @Andrew They are scattered in the atmosphere and after that they travel paralel with the moonlight which obviously arrive from the Moon.

Comment: Why should the Moon look blue. If blue moonlight is scattered in the atmosphere, it would look red ?

Comment: @ProfRob The moonlight is white but combined with the blue sunlight scattered in the atmosphere that both enter in our eyes paralelly should have as effect some kind of white-blue Moon image.. ..

Comment: On what basis are you saying that doesn't happen?

Answer (score 4):

The moon appears pretty blue [during the day](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=moon%20during%20the%20day&t=brave&iax=images&ia=images). This is because the atmosphere is scattering blue photons in all directions, including towards your eyes. When you look at the moon during the day, you see it’s light, plus the light coming from the atmosphere. At night, the moon does not appear blue because the atmosphere is not scattering blue light.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: I upvoted. Just a very minor friendly suggestion: in the last sentence, as written it could be read that the scattering properties of the atmosphere itself change at night. It might make the sentence a little more clear to say "the atmosphere is not scattering blue light from the sun."